# Good *free* markov modeling tools?

Tags: performance, markov-chains

I would like to use Markov models for some architecture simulations, but don't have a budget to buy anything like, eg, SHARPE.  Does anyone know of a freeware tool, either platform-independent or available for Mac OS/X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe You can try [this](http://www.tsi.enst.fr/~cappe/h2m/) with [GNU Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)